# How to resolve this conversion probability task - Naive Bayes in R or Python

Tags: python, r, bayesian, naivebayes

I have this task:
[image]

Do Anyone can help me with - how to resolve this in R or Python using machine learning and some of the R/Python packages for Naive Bayes using Bayesian theorem. Or any other useful way (KNN/something else)

I've used this code in R, but do I need something more for this 10^9

```
 library(e1071)

data.conversions <- data.frame(Country = c("US","FR","US"), Browser = c("Firefox","Chrome","Chrome"), Site = c("Website1", "Website2", "Website2"), Ad = c("Ad4","Ad7","Ad4"), Converted = c("y","n","y") )
data.conversions

class(data.conversions$Converted)
model <- naiveBayes(Converted~., data=data.conversions)


convertion <- data.frame(Country = c("FR"), Browser = c("Firefox"), Site = c("Website1"), Ad = c("Ad4"))
predict(model, convertion)
#The prediction shows "y" -> yes for conversion for the user in this model.

test<- predict(model, convertion)

convertion$Converted <- test

Predicted <- rbind(data.conversions, convertion)

newdf <- rbind(data.conversions, convertion)
dim(data.conversions)
dim(convertion)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 10^9 means you have a billion records?

Comment: And Should I do something more. Or this in the code example is enough?